# Change Default Path of .env files in ReactJs ViteJs Project

Tags: reactjs, environment, vite

I want to setup Multiple env file in ReactJs / ViteJs project, following the vite enDir documentation it should be something like that :

```
root
   |
   .env.dev
   ...
   .env.prod
```

but since it can become so messy when you have a lot of env files on the root, what i can do change vite config in order to get env variables from the **env folder**

```
root
   |
   env
      |
      .env.dev
      ...
      .env.prod
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can setup the .env file location trough the `envDir` parameter in the `defineConfig` object.

The solution is :

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  envDir: "./env"
});
```

Answer (score 5):

"vite": "4.3.4" just put the dir like :

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  envDir: "../"
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.